# Getting different output files

Tags: bash, output, fastq

I'm doing a test with these files:

```
comp900_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
comp900_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R2_001.fastq
comp900_c0_seq2_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
comp900_c0_seq2_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R2_001.fastq
comp995_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R2_001.fastq
comp995_c0_seq1_Xilano_1_AGTCAA_merge_R1_001.fastq
comp995_c0_seq1_Xilano_1_AGTCAA_merge_R2_001.fastq
```

I want to get the files that have the same code until the first _ (underscore) and have the code R1 in different output files. The output files should be called according with the code until the first _ (underscore).

-This is my code, but I'm having trouble on making the output files.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {900..995}; do
    if [[ ${i} -eq ${i} ]]; then
        cat comp${i}_*_R1_001.fastq
    fi
done
```

-I want to have two outputs:

One output will have all lines from:

```
comp900_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
comp900_c0_seq2_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
```

and its name should be `comp900_R1.out`

The other output will have lines from:

```
comp995_c0_seq1_Xilano_1_AGTCAA_merge_R1_001.fastq
```

and its name should be `comp995_R1.out`

Finally, as I said, this is a small test. I want my script to work with a lot of files that have the same characteristics.

Comment: Simply out of curiosity: Why do you need this condition: `if [[ ${i} -eq ${i} ]]; then`?

Comment: Moreover, it seems that all you need is `comp${i}`

Comment: What is your expected from this problem?

Comment: I am expecting a two files: the first one will have comp900_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq and comp900_c0_seq2_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq. the second one will have comp995_c0_seq1_Xilano_1_AGTCAA_merge_R1_001.fastq.

Comment: Maybe I misread your question. I thought you wanted to concatenate the files into new files `comp900`, `comp995` etc?

Comment: the condition : if [[ ${i} -eq ${i} ]]; means that if the first number that is going to read is equal to the second one, then cat the files by comp${i}_*_R1_001.fastq. I guess the condition is working because I get the expected result in my console. However, I'm new on doing scripts.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain myself very well.

Comment: Could you edit your post and show: What output-files should exist, and what should they contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
ls -1 *.fastq | awk -F_ '$8 == "R1" {system("cat " $0 ">>" $1 "_R1.out")}'
```

List all files `*.fastq` into `awk`, splitting on `_`. Check if 8:th part `$8` is `R1`, then append `cat >>` the file into first part `$1` + `_R1.out`, which will be `comp900_R1.out` or `comp995_R1.out`. It is assumed that no filenames contain spaces or other special characters.

Result:

File `comp900_R1.out` containing all lines from

```
comp900_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
comp900_c0_seq2_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
```

and file `comp995_R1.out` containing all lines from

```
comp995_c0_seq1_Xilano_1_AGTCAA_merge_R1_001.fastq
```

Answer (score 1):

My stab at a general solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *_R1_*; do
   code=$(echo $f | cut -d _ -f 1)
   cat $f >> ${code}_c0_seq1_Glicose_1_ACTTGA_merge_R1_001.fastq
done
```

Iterates over files with `_R1_` in it, then appends its output to a file based on `code`.

`cut` pulls out the code by splitting the filename (`-d _`) and returning the first field (`-f 1`).